# Increase Comment Author Gravatar Size On WordPress Default Comment Function

Tags: functions, comments, comment-form, gravatar, comments-template

I am new to WordPress theme development. I am designing a new theme and using less codes and file as I am starting from basic. I am adding comments and comment form in my `single.php` using `<?php comments_template(); ?>` only. This one line is showing my blog comments, comment navigation, comment form all things. But its showing my commenters gravatar in `32px` size that I want to increase. I know that if I will use `comments.php` then I can do it but **How To Increase Comment Author Gravatar Size?** in this circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you can't do it without using `comments.php`. Since WordPress 2.7, `comments.php` is important to display full features and customizable comments rest if you still want to use `<?php comments_template(); ?>` then you can edit anything in it except CSS.